# Upgrading Azure Functions to 5.0 : System.UriFormatException

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions, .net-5

I have been working on upgrading one of our Azure Functions implementations to .net 5. I have battled may demons already but just as I though I had sorted out all the config and dependency injection changes, it throws a curve ball at me. After `host.RunAsync` in `Main`, I get the following exception and I am at a bit of a loss as to the culprit. Has anyone run into and fixed this one?

```
System.UriFormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
  Source=System.Private.Uri
  StackTrace:
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress(String address, GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddGrpc>b__1_1(IServiceProvider p) in D:\a\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 58
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MySoftware.FunctionApp.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

My Program.cs main looks like:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry
    /// </summary>
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Function

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static class Function1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="req"></param>
        /// <param name="ctx"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext ctx)
        {
            ctx.GetLogger("out").LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.ReadAsString();

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `func host start` I also get the error "No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public."

```
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.953Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to dotnet-isolated. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:python
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.954Z] Reading functions metadata
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.955Z] 0 functions found
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.962Z] 0 functions loaded
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.969Z] Generating 0 job function(s)
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.978Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.983Z] Initializing function HTTP routes
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.985Z] No HTTP routes mapped
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.986Z]
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.994Z] Host initialized (53ms)
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.997Z] Host started (63ms)
[2021-04-09T07:37:04.998Z] Job host started
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
```

Comment: can you show us your code? and how do you upgrade from `.net core 3.1` to `.net 5`?

Comment: Corrected and added Main()

Comment: and how do you upgrade from .net core 3.1 to .net  5? just change some configuration?

Comment: https://daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5 and https://codetraveler.io/2021/02/12/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/

Comment: are you directly running the project from visual studio? currently, .net 5 function is not supported very well in visual studio. please try run it via this command `func host start` via Install the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).

Comment: Thanks - that gives me something to go on - I have updated the question - 0 Functions Found.

Comment: is your function method public? can you show us the function method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230928/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-murray-foxcroft).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, `.net 5 azure function` is not supported very well with tools like visual studio. You can run your function by using this command `func host start` in [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).

There is also a similar issue in github, you can refer to [the issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/331) for more details.

Comment: What does the exception have to do with running from Visual Studio?  We're getting this error from command line function running.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny same here. Did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen @Captain Prinny Try replacing `FunctionName` with `Function`

Comment: Using typescript and vscode on macos typescript flavor worked out of the box. I hope MS puts some time into getting their flagship language up to speed.

Answer (score 3):

It cost me half a day to figure this out, but you need to replace `[FunctionName("Function1")]` with `[Function("Function1")]`. Apparently this is something that changed in Azure Functions 3, but as far as I know it isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: that worked for me! The migration articles I saw were using [FunctionName] so I was at a loss...cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I didn't have the Azure Toolkit for Rider installed. Install this as a plugin and you will be good to go.