# System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://0' could not be parsed

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

Using **.NET5 Azure function** in **Visual Studio 2019**, I am getting the below exception from Program.cs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://0' could
> not be parsed

My `Program.cs` is below:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(data =>
                {
                    var result = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", false, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"AppSettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
                    return result;
                });

                services.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider>();
            })
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
            .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

The exception is being thrown from `host.Run()` in Debug mode. Any clue?

Comment: Hello @Yeasin Abedin, Could you please try to run your function by using this command `func host start` in [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) ,as mentioned in this SO Thread :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013422/upgrading-azure-functions-to-5-0-system-uriformatexception , And please let me know if it works or if the same issue still happening.

Comment: Please check my answer. I didn't have to use Azure Function Core Tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My issue has been solved. Once I set the `IConfiguration` from `ConfigureAppConfiguratio` middleware, the exception is gone

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                    {
                        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", false, true)
                            .AddJsonFile(
                                $"AppSettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json",
                                true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        
                    })
                    .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
                    .Build();

            host.Run();
}
```

Comment: `error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item [/private/tmp/foo/LocalFunctionProj/LocalFunctionProj.csproj]`

Comment: Came accross this when upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 7. This was 100% the issue.

Answer (score 49):

For me it was occurring in Rider.  The issue was that I was running the Function App as a .Net Project instead of as Azure Functions host.

[image: Rider Edit Run/Debug Configuration]

Comment: You need the plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11220-azure-toolkit-for-rider

Comment: How exactly did you run as Function App? Which steps did you follow? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Serhat, I agree that this is the correct answer and that it's not descriptive enough, so I'll answer.
Rider (three lines menu) -> Run -> Edit Configurations. 
You'll see items in the .net projects. Select them and click the minus.
Select the Azure functions host. Click the plus. Select the project that is your function app. Give it a name.
In my case the name was in conflict so I gave it a new name, but then had to close rider, delete the .idea folder and restart rider. Once I went back into the run configuration, I was able to rename the configuration correctly.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem in VS 2022, .NET 7. Adding the nuget package for

> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk

solved this for me.

Comment: Solved my issue as well with a function I was migration from .Net 6 to .Net 7.

Comment: When moving from .NET7.0 STS to .NET.8.0 LTS

Answer (score 5):

In my case, shutting down Visual Studio 2022 and opening it in Administrator mode solved my issue

Comment: It did not resolve the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `func start` instead of `dotnet run` in your command line.
Im using VS Code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after installing VS Enterprise, even though I had previously been using the free version. For me, updating the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` to the latest version resolved the problem.

Comment: @Manfred I don't know if this is your case, but the issue was with the newest Visual Studio, so I had to update the library after months of not updating VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, in my case I had 2 installations of visual studio, one of them didn't have the "Azure development" workload included, and I was trying to run the Function app using that installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing package. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
Fixed after a lot of pain

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Visual Studio 2022 after installing .NET8, F5 debug would no longer open into the local Azure Functions runtime.

To get it working again, I had to go to Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Azure functions. Then check for updates and install updates, and restart Visual Studio.

This is documented in a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2121#issuecomment-1930137063).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and I found out that the problem was caused by the `services.AddConfigurations` method in the `ConfigureServices` extension method. This method was overriding the settings done by the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` method. To fix this, I had to include the `hostContext.Configuration` in the `AddConfigurations()` method, like this:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

    services.AddConfigurations(c => c.SetBasePath(location)
                        .AddJsonFile("example.settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration));
}).Build();
host.Run();
```

This way, the configuration from the `hostContext` is merged with the configuration from the JSON file, and the settings are not overridden. I hope this helps you solve your problem.