# .NET6 Isolated Azure Function Unit and Integration Test causes gRPC exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, grpc, .net-6.0

I have an isolated Azure Function that makes couple of HTTP POST calls. I am trying to write an integration test for them. But the test setup fails with a gRPC error.

Here is the Program.cs that configures the HttpClient with services.AddHttpClient();

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHttpClient();
            }).Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

The sample function looks like this:

```
public class AzFunctionEndpoint
{        
    public AzFunctionEndpoint(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ResolveEndpoint>();
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    [Function("azfunction")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "azs/azfunction")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        
        // Couple of other HTTP calls using httpClientFactory
        
        // return
        var res = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return res;
        
    }        

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
}
```

**The Function runs correctly on local machine and when deployed to Azure.**

Now I try and create an integration test with

```
public class AzFunctionEndpointIntegrationTests
{
    public AzFunctionEndpointIntegrationTests()
    {
        factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        var clientFactory = factory.Services.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();

        // THIS LINE CAUSES gRPC host error 
        client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AzFunction_Should_BeOK()
    {
        // POST to the azure function
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(HttpMethods.Post), "api/azs/azfunction");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private HttpClient client;
    private WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory;
}
```

The test code that tries to create HttpClient to invoke my function causes this exception

```
client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

**System.InvalidOperationException : The gRPC channel URI 'http://:51828' could not be parsed.**

I don't quite understand what is this error ! Any help on writing integration tests for Azure Functions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> System.InvalidOperationException : The gRPC channel URI
> 'http://:51828' could not be parsed.
>
> I don't quite understand what is this error ! Any help on writing
> integration tests for Azure Functions is appreciated.

Below are the few workaround may help to fix the above issue.

- Based on this [***`GitHub issue`***](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2032#issuecomment-941028418) the root cause we have observed that, May be due to the usage of incorrect `run/debug` configuration the IDE you are using.

Please make sure that you are using the same as suggested on the given `gitHub link` to run the application.

To write an [***Integration test you can refer this Example for your function app***](https://devkimchi.com/2021/08/26/azure-functions-integration-testing/).

***Example of sample code:-***

`test.cs`

```
[TestClass]
public class DefaultHttpTriggerTests
{
    private HttpClient _http;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        this._http = new HttpClient();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        this._http.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Given_OpenApiUrl_When_Endpoint_Invoked_Then_It_Should_Return_Title()
    {
        // Arrange
        var requestUri = "http://localhost:7071/api/openapi/v3.json";

        // Act
        var response = await this._http.GetStringAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenApiDocument>(response);

        // Assert
        doc.Should().NotBeNull();
        doc.Info.Title.Should().Be("OpenAPI Document on Azure Functions");
        doc.Components.Schemas.Should().ContainKey("greeting");

        var schema = doc.Components.Schemas["greeting"];
        schema.Type.Should().Be("object");
        schema.Properties.Should().ContainKey("message");

        var property = schema.Properties["message"];
        property.Type.Should().Be("string");
    }
}
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

***SO THREAD:-*** [***System.InvaliOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://0' could not be parsed***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051683/system-invalioperationexception-the-grpc-channel-uri-http-0-could-not-be-pa/70077749) .

***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Guide for running C# Azure Functions in an isolated process***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide)

Comment: It did not resolve the issue in my case :(