# .NET 6, Azure Function v4 in VS 2022: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:0' could not be parsed

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I am migrating an old solution containing projects versioned 2.1, 2.2, and 3.1 to 6.0. I've used Upgrade Assistant in VS to perform the migration and fixed all remaining build errors manually. 2 projects are azure function apps and with the upgrade (version was changed to v4).
The build works fine, but I am getting the below error when I run a function app in my local:

> Message=The gRPC channel URI 'http://:0' could not be parsed.
> Source=Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.GrpcWorkerClientFactory.GrpcWorkerClient.CreateClient()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.GrpcWorkerClientFactory.GrpcWorkerClient..ctor(GrpcHostChannel outputChannel, GrpcWorkerStartupOptions startupOptions, IMessageProcessor processor)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.GrpcWorkerClientFactory.CreateClient(IMessageProcessor messageProcessor)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.WorkerHostedService.d__3.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.d__9.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in some-folder-path-\Program.cs:line 7

I had a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051683/system-invalidoperationexception-the-grpc-channel-uri-http-0-could-not-be-p), but couldn't resolve my issue.

Before the upgrade, the project didn't have a Program.cs. The Upgrade Assistant created one and below are the contents:

```html
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an isolated function created in .NET 6 and it has following packages in .csproj. Please check if you are using latest versions of the packages in your project post upgrade.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
```

**Code:**

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

You can refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1883), to get more details.