asp.net core: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed. ONLY when run the file after local deploy
I am building a asp.net core function app. I can start and debug it perfectly, its throwing no errors:

All endpoints work, in debug and release mode.
Now I set: dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained -p:PublishSingleFile=false -p:UseAppHost=true -o "C:\MyAspNetApp"
to locally deploy my app, and after a while (and no errors) many, many files turn up in the target folder.
I double click on my main function app and get:

"The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' ".
However, I dont recall configuring gprc anywhere also the keyword in the entire solution doesnt come up. I am developing an on prem function app with no azure integration.
What could be the issue?
Here is my program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        var authOptions = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OidcAuthOptions)).Get<OidcAuthOptions>();
        services
            .AddHttpClient()
            .AddTransient<NtlmRequestSender>()
            .AddTransient<PrintDocumentAction>()
            .AddTransient<OpenDocumentAction>()
            .AddSingleton<LoginStateModel>()

            // Register NtlmRequestSenderService as both hosted and injectable service
            .AddSingleton<NtlmRequestSenderService>() // Register it as a singleton for DI
            .AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<NtlmRequestSenderService>()) // Also register it as a hosted service

            .AddHostedService<EndpointTriggerService>();

    })
    .Build();

string trayAppPath = @"C:\Users\info\source\repos\Navcon\NAV.LocalService\NAV.TrayApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\NAV.TrayApp.exe"; 
Process.Start(trayAppPath);

host.Run();


are you using func start ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2211, https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2099 - also see this similar SO question which cites packages and config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246931/net-6-azure-function-v4-in-vs-2022-the-grpc-channel-uri-http-0-could-not

no, im not using this; but it seems the tickets are unsolved...
